# Semantic Security of Modified Textbook/Raw RSA

Tags: rsa, chosen-plaintext-attack, semantic-security

Here's a modification of the textbook RSA scheme, in an attempt to achieve semantic security.

**Key generation**: chooses public key $pk = (N,e)$ and secret key $sk = d$ as in any RSA-based encryption scheme.

**Encrypting message $m \in \mathbb{Z}^*_N$ using  $pk$**: Choose $x\gets \mathbb{Z}^*_N$, output $\mathsf{ct}_1 = x^e \bmod N$, $\mathsf{ct}_2 = (m + x \bmod N)^e \mod N$. Output $(\mathsf{ct}_1, \mathsf{ct}_2)$.

**Decryption of ciphertext using $sk$**: Recover $x$ and $m+x$ from the two ciphertext components, then compute $m$.

Is this scheme IND-CPA secure? (that is, the adversary receives the public key, then must output two messages $m_0, m_1$. It receives the encryption of one of them, and must guess which one was encrypted) The usual attacks against textbook RSA don't seem to work here.

Thanks!

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks, by semantic security I meant IND-CPA security. You are right, if $\mathbb{Z}_N$ was used, then one of the messages could be $0$ itself, and its encryption will be distinguishable from a non-zero element's encryption. 
However, if the message space is $\mathbb{Z}^*_N$, would we have an IND-CPA attack? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes $m_0=0$ was the attack I had in mind. I do not immediately see another. I think you mean $\mathbb Z_N\setminus\{0\}$, not $\mathbb Z_N^*$ (the later also excludes $p$, $q$, $2p$…) Note: mathematically, $\mathsf{ct}_2=(m+x)^e\bmod N$ works just as well as the new version.

Comment: Is there an origin for this?

Comment: I am teaching textbook RSA, and a few students in the class proposed this variant. I couldn't find an attack (but also don't see how to prove this secure). I wonder if it makes sense to look at this scheme in some idealised model (such as the generic ring model).

Comment: By some pizza to those students...